Issue: Unable to Access WordPress Admin and Database Errors
Description:
I recently encountered an issue with my WordPress site that has left me unable to access my WordPress admin area. Here’s a detailed breakdown of the situation:
Background:
I changed my WordPress admin login URL from the default IP to a custom URL: https://xxxx.com/login. I used plugin.
A few days ago, I attempted to change my WordPress login password via wordpress.com/site.
Problems Encountered:

Login Issue:

I found that I cannot reach my WordPress admin URL through wordpress.com/site.
I am unable to log into my WordPress admin URL (https://xxxx.com/login) using my original username and password. I didn’t change the original ID/PW. It’s my fault.
2. Database Issue:
My server and database are hosted on Google Cloud, and I am using Bitnami with Apache and MariaDB.
I attempted to change the MariaDB password through SSH, but encountered the following error: ERROR 1968 (28000).
Steps Taken:
Attempted to change the MariaDB password through SSH, resulting in the error mentioned above.
Environment Details:
Hosting: Google Cloud Platform
Stack: Bitnami WordPress Stack
Server: Apache
OS: Client 15.2 for Linux (x86-64) readline 5.1
Database: MariaDB 11.2.2
Request:
I am looking for guidance on the following:
How to regain access to my WordPress admin area (https://xxxx.com/login)? I used plugin but I don't know how to stop it or uninstall it.
How to resolve the MariaDB password change error (ERROR 1968 (28000))?
Any help or guidance on troubleshooting these issues would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

To deactivated the Plugin, you can simple go to following path, find the plugin folder and rename it to anything
WordPress Root Folder > wp-content > plugins

I wanted to share my experience and express my gratitude for the support I received. Following the advice from StackExchange, I navigated to the WordPress root folder, then to wp-content > plugins, and renamed the plugin folder to deactivate it. Additionally, I followed the detailed step-by-step guidance from ChatGPT to amend the plugins for the login URL and used WP-CLI to reset the password. This allowed me to access the wp-admin dashboard successfully. Thank you very much for your help!
